# JavaScript - How to merge/append to an Object/Array - ReactJS - Spread Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread-syntax

I am having trouble trying to append something my object, using the spread syntax.

Depending on the fact whether the NewPerson is there for a private/professional occasion I want to append additional key/values to the object/array.

Somehow it does not work. Hopefully someone can help me out. :(

```js
var NewPerson = [
    Firstname: this.state.addPersonFirstname,
    Lastname: this.state.addPersonLastname,
    Birthday: this.state.addPersonBirthday,
    Occasion: this.state.addPersonOccasion,
];


if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionProfessional') {
    NewPerson = [
        ...NewPerson,
        ...[ProfEmployerName: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerName],
        ...[ProfEmployerPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerPLZ],
        ...[ProfEmployerCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerCity],
        ...[ProfEmployerUVT: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerUVT]
    ]
}


if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionPrivate') {
    NewPerson = [
        ...NewPerson,
        ...[PrivPersonStreet: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonStreet],
        ...[PrivPersonPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonPLZ],
        ...[PrivPersonCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonCity]
    ]
}


var CombinedPersons


if (PreviousPersons === null) {
    CombinedPersons = NewPerson
} else {
    CombinedPersons = [...PreviousPersons, ...NewPerson]
}
```

Comment: In your very first lines you are mistaking array brackets `[]` with object braces `{}`. The code that follows it is completely off as well since you're struggling to understance the difference. Lemme rewrite that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up arrays and objects in this case. You want all the properties of a person isolated to a single entity. `Object` works out best in such cases.

```js
var NewPerson = {
  Firstname: this.state.addPersonFirstname,
  Lastname: this.state.addPersonLastname,
  Birthday: this.state.addPersonBirthday,
  Occasion: this.state.addPersonOccasion,
};


if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionProfessional') {
  NewPerson = {
    ...NewPerson,
    ProfEmployerName: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerName,
    ProfEmployerPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerPLZ,
    ProfEmployerCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerCity,
    ProfEmployerUVT: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerUVT
  }
}


if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionPrivate') {
  NewPerson = {
    ...NewPerson,
    PrivPersonStreet: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonStreet,
    PrivPersonPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonPLZ,
    PrivPersonCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonCity
  ]
}


var CombinedPersons


if (PreviousPersons === null) {
  CombinedPersons = [NewPerson]
} else {
  CombinedPersons = [...PreviousPersons, {...NewPerson}]
}
```

`PreviousPersons` will be an array of person objects.

Comment: Minor suggestion in the last line of code: replace `{...NewPerson}` with just `NewPerson` if I understand the intention of OP correctly.

Comment: Sure, we could do that but just did not want to have the reference of the original object in the array.

Comment: in the if (PreviousPersons === null) { it should be CombinedPersons = [NewPerson] I guess?

Comment: @ducmai My bad. Thought I fixed that as well. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should use Objects instead Array because Objects have key-value pairs. You could do (in ES6 syntax):

```
const { addPersonOccasion } = this.state;

const isProfessional = addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionProfessional';
const isPrivate = addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionPrivate';

const NewPerson = {
    Firstname: this.state.addPersonFirstname,
    Lastname: this.state.addPersonLastname,
    Birthday: this.state.addPersonBirthday,
    Occasion: this.state.addPersonOccasion,
    ...(isProfessional && {
      ProfEmployerName: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerName,
      ProfEmployerPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerPLZ,
      ProfEmployerCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerCity,
      ProfEmployerUVT: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerUVT
    }),
    ...(isPrivate && {
        PrivPersonStreet: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonStreet,
        PrivPersonPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonPLZ,
        PrivPersonCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonCity
    })
};


let CombinedPersons = [NewPerson];


if (PreviousPersons !== null) {
  CombinedPersons = [...PreviousPersons, ...CombinedPersons]
}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to spread the new properties...

You can:

```
if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionProfessional') {
    NewPerson = {
        ...NewPerson,
        ProfEmployerName: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerName,
        ProfEmployerPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerPLZ,
        //... and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of all your answers made the final version:

```js
    var NewPerson = {
      Firstname: this.state.addPersonFirstname,
      Lastname: this.state.addPersonLastname,
      Birthday: this.state.addPersonBirthday,
      SigImage: this.sigPad.getCanvas().toDataURL('image/png'),
      Occasion: this.state.addPersonOccasion,
    };

    if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionProfessional') {
      NewPerson = {
        ...NewPerson,
        ProfEmployerName: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerName,
        ProfEmployerPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerPLZ,
        ProfEmployerCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerCity,
        ProfEmployerUVT: this.state.addPersonOccasionProfEmployerUVT
      }
    }

    if (this.state.addPersonOccasion === 'OccasionPrivate') {
      NewPerson = {
        ...NewPerson,
        PrivPersonStreet: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonStreet,
        PrivPersonPLZ: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonPLZ,
        PrivPersonCity: this.state.addPersonOccasionPrivPersonCity
      }
    }
    // Save the user input to NewPerson var - End

      // Create combined var with PreviousPersons and NewPerson - Start
      var CombinedPersons
      if (PreviousPersons === null) {
        CombinedPersons = [NewPerson]
      } else {
        CombinedPersons = [ ...PreviousPersons, NewPerson ]
      }
      // Create combined var with PreviousPersons and NewPerson - End
```